# Passing scrollTop to ionic component on scroll event

Tags: ionic3

I have added a subscription to `ionScroll` which displays the content information in the `console.log`

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
...
this.content.ionScroll.subscribe(ev => {
  this.windowYPosition = ev.scrollTop;
  console.log('event', ev);
});
```

[link to console.log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63idz.png) ( i cant add images inline yet )

The event gets fired on each scroll and the `this.windowYPosition` variable gets updated,. However if i try pass this to a component

```
<tg-navbar page="overview" [windowPosition]="windowYPosition"></tg-navbar>
```

Or even if i try display it on the same view `dashboard.html`

```
{{windowYPosition}}
```

It never updates in the component or the view. It is always the assigned value of `0` even though i am assigning it on the scroll event. If i add the `console.log('var',this.windowYPosition)` below the assignment the log will show the new value.

Does anyone know why the value is not updating at all in the view or the component?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `ev` with brackets like so: `this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((ev) => {
  this.windowYPosition = ev.scrollTop;
  console.log('event', ev);
});`

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem now. Have you found a solution for this ? Thanks!

Comment: @Pierre I kinda got it working with the mutate observable .. i followed this guide, https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-scroll-vanish-directive-with-ionic-web-components/

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting :)